# Make hierarchical back button in either javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I'm creating a mobile theme for my website and I decided it'd be nice to make a back button for people that shows up in the header of the site next to the title. Now I figured out how to make a back button in both javascript or php, and this works just fine in taking the user back to the last page visited.

Javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Go Back From Whence You Came!" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  echo "<a href='$url'>back</a>";
?>
```

Now the issue is I don't want people to go back to the last page they visited but rather go up the hierarchy of pages back up to the home page eventually.

Right now this is how it works:

- I go to page A
- Then I go to page B, and click to go to page C.
- When I click the back button on page C, I get to page B.
- When I click the back button on page B, I get to page C.

How I want it to work:

- I go to page A
- Then I go to page B, and click to go to page C.
- When I click the back button on page C, I get to page B.
- Then when I click the back button on page B, I get back to page A.

So I need it to work more like the normal back button on the browser and not just take you back to the last page you were on because that leads to an infinite loop which I'm sure will make people upset.

Also it's probably worth noting that I'm working on a huge site with tons of content built off of Drupal 6 on 1 page.tpl.php file. So I can't simply say if on page B go to page A but it needs to be something dynamic that works no matter where I plug it.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: hmmm.. would it not be better if you just leave the page without the back button since there is a build in back button for the browser which people know exactly how it works? It just seems like you are adding something that does not have value

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to add this button (which might screw up the forward button for your browser) you can probably do it with a php session object or whatever it is called, I dunno php that well but here is the logic which I think will work

Each time you go to a page, save URl in this persistence variable/array, output the last entered URL as the url of the button then add current URL to this array. when you click the button you need to delete the URL in the link from the array and everything after it.

a-b-c-d
if you are on page d and press back, you need to remove c and d and output the link as b
OR
if you are on d and press back you need to remove d and output b as URL
then when are at the end meaning you are on page a, the button will disappear.

his seems like a lot of work to put in something that exists in every browser